# Objective-J with windows

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

Is there any way to work on Objective-J in Windows platform ?
Any such IDE, Compiler for Objective-J for windows ?

Is Cappuccino developed only for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-J can be developed in Windows. If you don't need to compile Cappuccino itself, you should be able to just download the starter pack on http://cappuccino.org/download/ and go from there. The `jake` and `objjc` compilers should work just fine (although I haven't tested it). If you want to compile Cappuccino yourself, you'll probably need to install Cygwin to get `gcc` (its preprocessor is used).

Many Cappuccino coders use the Sublime Text 2 to edit Objective-J and Cappuccino code. That editor is available for Windows and I expect the Objective-J and Cappuccino [package](https://github.com/aparajita/Cappuccino-Sublime) will work just fine there.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the started pack and I opened index-debug.html , It worked fine with firefox , I did change the code and reloaded it, it worked fine , but in error console it was throwing errors like ' main.j not well-formed '. Then loaded it in Chrome, it not even launched again in console there is an error like could not find file main.j and appcontroller.j. I downloaded sublime text2 again same issue. I think there is something else we need to do. please let me know.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support loading web apps from file:// URLs. You need to run a web server to serve the files and surf to localhost. Firefox has similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure none of our build tools actually work on Cygwin. If they do, there are a lot of hoops you have to jump through. That will be something we have to work on when we move aeverything to node.js.

As for your question, like Alexander said, you don't need to compile it yourself... When you're ready to deploy, Andy Linux box will run the build tools just fine.